# how do i set the size of jquery buttons?

Tags: jquery

My game is using jquery buttons for the inventory system. The problem is that the buttons are being resized automatically depending on the text in the button, which changes depending on what is in the inventory.

How can I set the size of the buttons? I would also like to set a background image for the buttons depending on the item.

** these are jqueryUI buttons like this:

```
<button id="invOn1" style="float: left;">Loading...</button>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you using HTML Buttons with JQuery event handlers, or JQuery UI buttons?

Comment: Are you using the jQuery Button plugin? ==> http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button

Answer (score 0):

try this solution :

```
$("button").button().css('width','350px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your CSS

```
.ui-button{
    line-height: 0.9em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
```